# Is it possible to lazy load a set of components/modules in React from a url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, lazy-loading

I have a React application that I'm building that will support 3rd party developers writing their own components that we will test and then host on our company CDN.  I have dynamic loading of modules working using `@loadable/component`, but I can't figure out how to get this to work for something that lives at a web address.

Here's what I have so far for lazy loading components.  The components to be fetched are outlined in a .json file.  This .json file is parsed and a  component I wrote fetches the index.js at that location and loads that component into the application.

```
import moduleMetaData from "../thirdparty_modules"; //the json file outlining which modules to load
import loadable from "@loadable/component";
import React from "react";

const Module = (props) => {
    let id = props.id;
    let LoadedModule = null;

    if (!!moduleMetaData[id]) {
        let moduleLocation = moduleMetaData[id].location;

        LoadedModule = loadable(() => import(`${moduleLocation}`), {
            fallback: <div>Loading Module...</div>
        });
    }    
    return <LoadedModule/>;
}

export default Module;
```

Here's the .json file this is using:

```
{
  "module1": {
    "name": "ModuleTest1",
    "location": "./main/module1/index"
  }
}
```

I then use this `<Module />` component inside of my App.js to load the modules into my application:

```
const App = () => {
    const GetModules = () => {
        let loadedModules = [];
        for(let key in moduleMetaData){
            loadedModules.push(<Module key={key} id={key}/>);
        }

        return loadedModules;
    }

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                routes
            }}
        >
            <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                        <Auth>
                            <Router history={history}>
                                <FuseAuthorization>
                                    <FuseTheme>
                                        <FuseLayout/>
                                    </FuseTheme>
                                </FuseAuthorization>
                            </Router>
                        </Auth>
                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

                    {/*LOAD MODULES*/}
                    {GetModules()}
                </Provider>
            </StylesProvider>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

This code is allowing me to lazy load components and modules from within my `/src` directory, provided that the path to the index file of each module is added to thirdparty_modules.json.

The issue I'm having is that I cannot get this to work for modules that are being stored on an external web server.  If I move the module1 directory from `./src/main/module1` to our CDN with an example address being `https://our.cdn.net/module1`, and then update my .json location to be `https://our.cdn.net/module1/index`, I get the error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module 'https://our.cdn.net/module1/index'

How can I get my lazy loading of components to load from an external url, rather than having to load from my local `/src` directory?

Comment: your url is not correct. it says `can't find module`/

Comment: It is correct, I get the same `can't find module` error even if I use a local path.  I get that error for any path that is not inside my /src directory

Comment: Have you tried it with `lazy` from react, or seen `Tyler McGinnis` tutorial explaining this. Let me have breakfast.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot use it with `import`, you can still retrieve the data with, for example, the Fetch API and return it.

Something like

```
        LoadedModule = loadable(() => fetch(moduleLocation).then(res => res.text())
```

should work just fine.

Comment: The url I need to fetch is a javascript file though, not json.  Would something like this work for loading a .js file and loading the component outlined in the js file into my application?

Comment: Sorry, stupid habit - it should be `res.text()` of course to read the response into a string... Gonna change the answer.